# My app still runs after it stops. How can I stop it?

Tags: android

My android app is designed so that the only way the user can stop it is to hit the back key on the phone.  When that key is hit, the onStop event does indeed execute where I have a log command and I execute super.onStop();

But the app does not stop.  I know this because I have a timer that goes off ever so often and sends me an email containing debug entries.

(it doesn't send the email via the phone rather via a post to my server that sends the email).

After I "stop the app" I keep getting emails all day long - it's still running for sure.

If I examine the phone's (Galaxy S3) "running" apps it is not listed but if I look at the properties of the app, "force close" is enabled.  If I hit "force close" the app then stops sending the emails.

How can I get this app to stop?

Thanks,
Gary

Here is my EDIT . . .

The Timer below executes my getRTlegsFromServer which calls an asynctask that talks to my REST service.  DebugLog sends me email via another REST service.  All this works very well, in fact so well that it can't be stopped.  I get the "onStop event" in my email and then, after that, more DebugLog messages all day long until I force stop on the phone.

```
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            TimerMethod();
        }
    }, 0, 10*1000);  


private void TimerMethod()
    {
        //debugLog("TimerMethod is executing", false);  


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                if (timeForAnother == true)
                {
                    getRTlegsFromServer();
                }
                else
                {
                    DebugLog.debugLog("NOT making server call because timeForAnother is false", false);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        DebugLog.debugLog("onStop event ", true);
        //timer.cancel();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

The timer.cancel() is commented out (my attempt to stop it) because it gets a NullPointerException.  I have read on other threads that the KillProcess solution is a bad idea.  This app does not use any services.

Comment: "I know this because I have a timer that goes off ever so often" -- please edit your question to explain what this "timer" is and how it is implemented. Do you literally mean `Timer` with a `TimerTask`?

Comment: Are you using any `service`? If so then stop the service.

Comment: To fully stop an app to avoid "force close" button activated in app's task status property, you can use `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running several test programs I can prove that calling finish() and having the program complete the onDestroy event does not stop the activity from running.  Timers still run and the program can send email, play sounds, etc.  The only thing that stops a program is having the user go to application settings and "force stop".  There is apparently no way to duplicate this programatically.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `onStop()` means that the Activity was stopped but not that the application is no longer active. It also does not mean, that the user has stopped the application. He/she could also have rotated the device (this also stops and destroys the Activity and recreates, restarts it).

Two things to look at are:

- To stop an Activity use `finish()`. And wherever you call `finish()` you should also `cancel()` the timer.
- Instead of `onStop()` to really react on the event where **the user** has left the application (back button, home button, ...) override `onUserLeaveHint()`.

I was confused about the way Android handles the Activity lifecycle. So I wrote a simple Activity that overrides all callbacks and logs them when called. Here's the output:

```
First Start
    onCreate
    onStart
    onResume

Turn orientation
    onPause
    onSaveInstanceState
    onStop
    onDestroy
    onCreate
    onStart
    onResume

Switch to another App
    onUserLeaveHint
    onPause
    onSaveInstanceState
    onStop

Get back to this App
    onRestart or onDestroy, onCreate
    onStart
    onResume

Press Home Button
    onUserLeaveHint
    onPause
    onSaveInstanceState
    onStop

Start another Application
---

Start this Application again
    onRestart/onCreate
    onStart
    onResume
```

Comment: I have android:screenorientation=portrait which I understand nixes events when the phone is turned horizontal.  I overrode onUserLeaveHint but it never executed when I hit the back button.  However onStop and onDestroy did indeed execute but the app is still sending me emails.

Comment: When you press the back button, what other Activity comes than to front? Is it the Home Screen or another Activity from your App?

Comment: To especially react on the hone button you need to overide `onBackPressed()`. Make sure that you call `timer.cancel()` in this case too. The call is commented out in your question above.

Comment: jobi, as I said in my edit, the timer.cancel gets a NullPointerException in the onStop Event so that's why it is commented out.  When I hit the back button it goes back to the phone's home screen.

Comment: +1 for OnUserLeaveHint ... I always learn a new callback to override :=)

Answer (score 0):

You did not cancel your Timer. That's why you keep receiving emails.

In `onStop()` method call `timer.cancel();` this would probably fix your problem.